# Scrollable OptionMenu on Customtkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, customtkinter

I am creating a GUI app using Customtkinter. I have created an Option Menu with large data from a list as below:

```
cards = [
        "2s","3s","4s","5s","6s","7s","8s","9s","10s","Js","Qs","Ks","As"
        "2h","3h","4h","5h","6h","7h","8h","9h","10h","Jh","Qh","Kh","Ah"
        "2d","3d","4d","5d","6d","7d","8d","9d","10d","Jd","Qd","Kd","Ad"
        "2c","3c","4c","5c","6c","7c","8c","9c","10c","Jc","Qc","Kc","Ac"
       ]

root=ctk.CTk()

blk_combobox=ctk.CTkOptionMenu(root,values=cards)
blk_combobox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The code runs like a charm. However, since there are many values in the option menu, I get this weird looking up and down arrows that allows me to go up or down to make a selection. How to enable mouse scroll or add a scroll bar into the option menu? These arrows are not user friendly at all.

Comment: It's impossible because Customtkinter uses the ```tkinter.Menu```, which uses the system menu component.